# Material ui checkbox css is overriding across the components in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to override material UI checkbox css in my Home Component and it is working fine. But there are side effects like css of checkbox in form component is overriding. Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

HTML used

```
 <mat-checkbox formControlName="home">
  Home
</mat-checkbox>
```

css used for over riding by default it is grey color

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Form component mat checkbox - for this component also it is overriding border color to blue without writing any css

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="form">
  Form
</mat-checkbox>
```

I believe this is happening due to usage of **::ng-deep**

I even tried **ViewEncapsulation** also in the Home component. It is still overriding css in Form component and other css in both the components.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply the style only inside a specific child component, add the `:host` selector to the following code in the CSS of that component:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

This will scope this rule to all checkboxes which are in this current component and all its children and will work pretty well in case of routed components.

But if you want to stick this css rule only for home page template then you can use:

*home.component.css*

```
.mat-checkbox ::ng-deep  .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Angular will replace it with:

```
.mat-checkbox[_ngcontent-rvb-c0] .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: blue !important;
}
```

where `_ngcontent-rvb-c0` is unique identifier of current compoent

Comment: Wouldn't it is also override checkboxes in child components? Wouldn't be it better to use `.mat-checkbox ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-frame` in home.component.css?

Comment: I meant using the code above in `home.component.css` (I will update the answer). According to my tests, we must also specify `:home` even if `::ng-deep` is in the child CSS.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this code should go to home.component.css.

Comment: @yurzui - Was your suggestion about swapping `::ng-deep` and `.mat-checkbox`? I haven't tried that (and my stackblitz is not configured for testing it).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm4bxn?file=src/app/child/child.component.css

Comment: And compare with https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm4bxn-8vurb5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html

Comment: OK. I see. I had tested for a simple `input` element in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gcja7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-section.component.css).

Comment: Yep, my suggestion is to swap ::ng-deep with .mat-checkbox in order to scope css rules only for those checkboxes which are in home page. But maybe we are not aware of all OP use cases and your solution will work for those cases

Comment: @yurzui - You can post your suggestion as an answer. I will delete mine. :-)

Comment: Let's improve your answer :)

Comment: @yurzui - I just realize that I misread your example (or the question). To me, the Home component was a child component, and the OP wanted to limit the CSS to that child, like child-1 in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm4bxn-rrk3u9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild-1.component.css).